# Introspecting Django queryset field lookups

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm building a querybuilder in Django for something similar to an issues dashboard, which allows users to query and save dashboards for custom subsets of the issues in our database (e.g., all issues assigned to team A, created by client X, and created or updated in the current quarter). The frontend would allow the user to interact with the issues API to generate the list of issues they're looking for, and to save the filter criteria so they can visit the page and see an updated list of issues that match the filter criteria.

I'm thinking of saving the filter criteria as a dictionary in a JSONField, which I'd pass to the `Model.objects.filter` and the `Q` APIs.

I'd like to provide the Frontend a list of all eligible Field lookups (e.g., `exact`, `iexact`, `contains`, `icontains`, `in`, `gt`, etc.). Is there a class I can introspect to programmatically get a list of these lookups?

I read through the [Field Lookup Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) tried looking through the [Django source code](https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/django), but couldn't find something similar to `Model._meta.get_fields()` for introspecting the fields on a model, as listed in the [Model _meta API docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems you are looking for this?

```py
from django.db.models.fields  import Field
f = Field()
f.get_lookups()
{'exact': <class 'django.db.models.lookups.Exact'>, 'iexact': <class 'django.db.models.lookups.IExact'>, 'gt': <class 'django.db.models.lookups.GreaterThan'>, 'gte': <class 'django.db.models.lookups.GreaterThanOrEqual'>, 'lt': <class 'django.db.models.lookups.LessThan'>, 'lte': <class 'django.db.models.lookups.LessThanOrEqual'>, 'in': <class 'django.db.models.lookups.In'>, 'contains': <class 'django.db.models.lookups.Contains'>, 'icontains': <class 'django.db.models.lookups.IContains'>, 'startswith': <class 'django.db.models.lookups.StartsWith'>, 'istartswith': <class 'django.db.models.lookups.IStartsWith'>, 'endswith': <class 'django.db.models.lookups.EndsWith'>, 'iendswith': <class 'django.db.models.lookups.IEndsWith'>, 'range': <class 'django.db.models.lookups.Range'>, 'isnull': <class 'django.db.models.lookups.IsNull'>, 'regex': <class 'django.db.models.lookups.Regex'>, 'iregex': <class 'django.db.models.lookups.IRegex'>}
```

Source code:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/bae053d497ba8a8de7e4f725973924bfb1885fd2/django/db/models/lookups.py#L361 - check the whole file.

There is also much older commit which might help, if you only want a static list: https://github.com/django/django/blob/d4e578d0f64971483ded49f9cae460ea174b5138/django/db/models/sql/constants.py#L11 but this one is not available for importing anymore.